# Uniqueness validation in django form (Both ADD and EDIT)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

Here, I wanted to achieve mobile number uniqueness validation in both conditions i.e. at the time of ADD and EDIT form details.

I am facing a problem in form edit mode because I am unable to perform uniqueness validation in form edit submit.

I wanted only a single mobile no to be stored in a database. While I am editing the form it is bypassing my logic and allowing duplicate entries from EDIT.

Could you guys suggest any solution for uniqueness validation?

```
forms.py

class StudentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=10)
    city = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=10)
    mobile_no = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=10)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(StudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  

    def clean_mobile_no(self):
        mobile_no = self.cleaned_data.get('mobile_no')
        id = self.request.POST.get('id')

        if stu_id:
            if Student.objects.filter(mobile_no=mobile_no).count()>1:
                raise forms.ValidationError("You have already added mobile no.")
            else:
                return mobile_no
        elif mobile_no and Student.objects.filter(mobile_no=mobile_no).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Alreadsy exists.")
        return mobile_no

views.py

def add_edit_(request, stu_id=None):
    if stu_id:
        stu = Student.objects.get(pk=stu_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentForm(request.POST, request=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = request.POST['name ']
            city = request.POST['ccity']
            mobile_no = form.cleaned_data['mobile_no']

                if stu_id:
                stu.name=name
                stu.ccity=city
                stu.mobile_no=mobile_no
                cstu.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Edit Successfully...')
                return redirect('/.../')
            else:
                p = Student(name=name, city=city, mobile_no=smobile_no
                            )
                p.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Information added Successfully...')
                return redirect('/../')
    elif id:
        form = CStudentForm(initial={'name':stu.name, 
               'city':stu.city,'mobile_no':std.mobile_no '})
    else:
        form = StudentForm()

    context = {

        'form': form,
        'stu_id':stu_id,
    }

    return render(request, 'student.html', context=context)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want to check that mobile phone is valid or you want to check if in you DB has another Student object with the same mobile phone?

Comment: if  DB has another Student object with the same mobile phone then it should display a message "Mobile no should ]be unique"